# Is there something wrong with my code here? PHP mail()

Tags: php, email

Seriously.  My hosting company says that there's something wrong with my Php code.  I'm not getting any errors from them, and they say it's not my CSS.  Please help.

```
    <?php

/* Subject and Email Variables */

    $emailSubject = 'Bookem danno!';
    $webMaster = 'info@mywebsite.com';

/* Gathering Data Variables */

    $nameField = $_POST['name'];
    $cellField = $_POST['cell'];
    $emailField = $_POST['email'];
    $dateField = $_POST['date'];
    $timeField = $_POST['time'];
    $lengthField = $_POST['length'];
    $inoutField = $_POST['inout'];
    $seenbeforeField = $_POST['seenbefore'];
    $detailsField = $_POST['details'];
    $p411Field = $_POST['p411'];
    $datecheckField = $_POST['datecheck'];
    $tobField = $_POST['tob'];
    $terField = $_POST['ter'];
    $otherField = $_POST['other'];
    $screennameField = $_POST['screenname'];
    $companyField = $_POST['company'];
    $worknoField = $_POST['workno'];
    $switchboardnoField = $_POST['switchboardno'];
    $memoField = $_POST['memo'];
    $subscribeField = $_POST['subscribe'];

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $name <br>
Cellphone: $cell <br>
Email: $email <br>
Date: $date <br>
Time: $time <br>
Length of appointment: $length <br>
Incall Outcall: $inout <br>
Have I seen you before: $seenbefore <br>
Details: $details <br>
P411: $p411 <br>
Datecheck: $datecheck <br>
TOB: $tob <br>
TER: $ter <br>
Other: $other <br>
Screen Name: $screenname <br>
Company: $company <br>
Direct Line: $workno <br>
Switchboard: $switchboardno <br>
Memo: $memo <br>
Subscribe Me: $subscribe <br>
EOD;

    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

echo "$result";


?>
```

Comment: This probably isn't the issue, but....you know you didn't set `$result`, right?  That's probably why you're not getting any output.

Comment: I actually do - it's just not showing up as it's html and includes a picture.  stack/overflow won't let me post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahem.  You're not using any of the variables you instantiated.  For example, initially you say this:

```
$emailField = $_POST['email'];
```

And then you say this:

```
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
```

There is no variable called `$email`.  There is one called `$emailField`, but you're not using that.  In fact, ALL of the variables from your `$_POST` are getting renamed with "Field" at the end, and then you're trying to refer to them later without the Field part.  Won't work.

Also, You've got a security vulnerability in that code.  Look:

```
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
```

You're assuming that $email is a nice safe value.  Suppose somebody fills in your form and tells it their email address is `0wned@example.com\r\nBcc: emai1@example.net, email2@example.org, etc...`, thereby causing your email server to send out hundreds or thousands of emails.

A spammer might do it for the sake of sending spam -- without having to maintain their own email server.

A bored and malicious person might do it just for the kick of seeing your domain blacklisted as a spammer.

An unethical corporate rival might do it to throw a monkey wrench into your ordering procedures in the hopes of driving your out of business. I am cursed with a good imagination...

Do yourself a favor and try this:

```
$email = str_replace( "\r\n", '', $_POST['email'] );
```

That will strip out any potential CR/LF pairs, so that nobody can inject their own headers into your email.

Comment: Thank you for that.  Will this happen even if I have the validation limit set to 30 characters?

Comment: Limiting to thirty characters would make it harder, but wouldn't eliminate the possibility.  Instead of sending one really long header, an attacker could write a script to submit your form over and over and over, each time with a different CC address.  Better to strip the `\r\n` from any data input by the user that might end up in the extra headers parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The trick is to *remove* the string `\r\n` from anything that the user typed in, before it is added to the headers.

Comment: where do i put this code exactly then $email = str_replace( "\r\n", '', $_POST['email'] );

Comment: Oh. What that does is get the value of $_POST['email'], strips out the CRLF, and saves it in a variable called $email.  So put it at the top where you're getting the variables from $_POST.

Answer (score 1):

You are happily using several variables you never define (and discarding some variables you actually set). That means that you are writing PHP code while having error reporting set to hide notices (or even set to hide all error messages). Whatever your problem is (you don't actually say) you are instructing PHP not to notify you. Read this: http://es2.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Answer (score 0):

$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
 replace this with your existing header.. i am not sure but it may help you...